# Canon EOS SDK (EDSDK): no operations after starting live view

Tags: edsdk

I am implementing a console application (going to be a dll) that controls a Canon EOS 600D using the EDSDK, implemented in C++.

I can get any function to work, change properties, take photos, start live view, and download live view content following examples from the documentation and sample app.

However, after I start live view, although it works fine, I cannot send any further commands or change any further properties on the camera. So, for example, I can't start autofocus or take a picture once live view is begun, even though these commands work fine otherwise.

The commands send fine (EdsSetPropertyData and EdsSendCommand return 0), but nothing happens. In the sample, you can execute commands after switching to Live View. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code but if you have made a loop for the live view it maybe can't go out so you can't access the rest of your code.

If it is this case try to launch the download of liveview by timer to be able to continue the execution of the code.